# Analysis services custom authentication

Tags: ssas, olap-cube, custom-authentication

I have made a web application to a company that provides users to input all invoices their company have paid. The company has departments in all cities and users can only see the data related to their cities. Now I designed an OLAP cube to provide them to analyze the data. Users open an excel pivot table over the application and connect to the SSAS but they can reach to the entire data.

My question is how can I show only the data related to their cities over SSAS? Any help will be appreciate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Analysis Services uses Windows authentication only with role-based security: . There are a number of ways to configure security to secure by dimension for Windows accounts assigned to roles. See this resource (it applies to versions SSAS 2005 and higher):

http://www.ssas-info.com/analysis-services-articles/51-security/3351-how-to-setup-basic-dimension-security-in-ssas

And see this for more advanced but flexible security:
http://sqlbits.com/Sessions/Event10/Advanced_Security_with_Analysis_Services_Multidimensional